# No operator matches the given name and argument type

Tags: postgresql

I tried to search in google for what's wrong with my sql statement but with no success!

> [Err] ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying * character varying
>   LINE 16: "Quantity" * "Unit Price" as "Total"
>
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

```
SELECT
"Trade Date",
"Due Date",
"Reference",
"Type",
"Symbol",
to_number("Quantity", '99999999D99')AS "Quantity",
to_number("Unit Price", '99999999D99')AS "Unit Price",
to_number("Amount", '99999999D99')AS "Amount",
to_number("Commission", '99999999D99')AS "Commission",
to_number("Charge", '99999999D99')AS "Charge",
to_number("VAT", '99999999D99')AS "VAT",
to_number("Net Amount", '99999999D99')AS "Net Amount",
"W/H",
to_number("Net Price", '99999999D99')AS "Net Price",
"Quantity" * "Unit Price" as "Total"

FROM
"public".aa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a column alias on the same level where you define it. So the reference to `"Quantity"` in the expression `"Quantity" * "Unit Price"` refers to the real (`varchar`) column, not to the alias you have defined.

If you want to access the value of the alias, you need to use a derived table:

```
SELECT "Trade Date",
       "Due Date",
       "Reference",
       "Type",
       "Symbol",
        "Quantity",
        "Unit Price",
        "Amount",
        "Commission",
        "Charge",
        "VAT",
        "Net Amount",
        "W/H",
        "Net Price",
        "Quantity" * "Unit Price" as "Total"
FROM (
  SELECT "Trade Date",
         "Due Date",
         "Reference",
         "Type",
         "Symbol",
          to_number("Quantity", '99999999D99') AS "Quantity",
          to_number("Unit Price", '99999999D99') AS "Unit Price",
          to_number("Amount", '99999999D99') AS "Amount",
          to_number("Commission", '99999999D99') AS "Commission",
          to_number("Charge", '99999999D99') AS "Charge",
          to_number("VAT", '99999999D99')  AS "VAT",
          to_number("Net Amount", '99999999D99') AS "Net Amount",
          "W/H",
          to_number("Net Price", '99999999D99')AS "Net Price"
  FROM "public".aa        
) t
```

---

However the much better solution would be to **not** store numbers in `varchar` columns. Numbers should be stored in columns defined as `numeric` or `integer`, **never** in columns defined as `varchar` or `text`